# How to save QR code as an contact in address book in iPhone

Tags: iphone, sdk, barcode

I have started using QR code in one of my app. I have successfully implemented Google API for scanning phone number and generate QR. I have got QR code working, How do i save that QR code as an contact inside address book in iPhone. Please if there is any kind of link or help let me know. Thanks for all the wonderful support

Comment: consider saving the QR Code as the contact image? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744017/addressbook-save-image-for-contacts-programatically

Answer (score 0):

Your QR should be encoded in a specific format. If your QR is vCard encoded, then you can parse that into a Contact and save it.

You might be able to use this as a reference:

[How to save contact info from vCard into iPhone's Contacts App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132326/how-to-save-contact-info-from-vcard-into-iphones-contacts-app)